# How to test select html control object using SpecFlow?

Tags: c#, testing, specflow, acceptance-testing

I have html select on page:

```
<select id="StateName" name="StateName">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="value1">value1</option>
<option value="value2">value2</option>
<option value="value3">value3</option>
<option value="value4">value4</option>
<option value="value5">value5</option>
</select>
```

I've already tried such step definition

```
[When("I select value \"(.*)\" of select object with id \"(.*)\"")]
public void ThenSelectValueOfSelect(string value, string selectId)
{
   var select = TestsRunner.Browser.GetElementById(selectId);
   select.Click();
   var item = TestsRunner.Browser.GetElementsByTag(@"option").SingleOrDefault(o => o.GetAttribute("value").Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
   item.Click();
}
```

As testsrunner browser I use firefox. The problem is select items are dropped down but concrete option isn't selected.

Answer (score 6):

I think it can be done much shorter/easier. The way I'm selecting values from dropdownboxes:

```
SelectElement dropdown = new SelectElement(Driver.FindElement(By.Id(dropdownID)));
dropdown.SelectByValue(valueToBeSelected);
```

It's pretty simple and straight forward and it just works.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but I suggest your code is appropriate for tests written in java, not in c#. But, nevertheless, I'll try to find some similar to `SelectElement` in c#. +1

Comment: I'm using C#, not Java ;). SelectElement is part of the IWebDriver interface which is used by Selenium.

Comment: @TimothyHeyden is correct. `SelectElement` is what you are looking for. It's commonly overlooked because it's part of the **Selenium.Support** NuGet package. If you install that package, you should have access to `SelectElement`. It's not part of the base selenium package.

Comment: This is a brilliant solution and should be marked correct.